# Kendo UI Editor appears empty

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a Kendo UI Editor using the code below, but the issue appears even if I copy and paste from the demo section for simplicity. The only difference is I have .Deferred() added.

The problem is the text does not appear in the field, nor can I edit the field when the page loads. I noticed when inspecting the element that the textarea has `display:none` which I am not sure if it is the problem or not.

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.Body)
      .Name("Body")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 740px;height:440px" })
      .Value(@<text>
                 @Html.Partial("~/Views/UserMailer/PanelInviteDefault.cshtml", Model)
              </text>).Encode(false).Deferred())
```

Any ideas on how to debug or fix?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this problem? If so, please add it as an answer because I am dealing with the same issue.

Comment: make sure the `.Name()` property matches to the Grid's column property name. Or numaroth make a separate question I'll try to answer it.

Comment: @CSharper This question is about an Editor not a Grid, so I'm not sure how your advice applies.  I would love to ask my own question, but since it would be essentially the same as this one I'm pretty sure it would be considered a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by Kendo trying to use functions that are not available in older versions of jQuery.

Upgrading your project to use at least [jQuery 1.8.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/09/20/jquery-1-8-2-released/) should solve the issue.